# tr.dynamic: no tr.dynamic policy could be found for the command 'ginstall'

Tags: makefile, installation, configure

I am trying to install [plib](http://plib.sourceforge.net/) from source to my `.local` directory. I have run the following commands successfully:

```
tar -xvf plib-1.8.5.tar.gz
cd plib-1.8.5/
./configure --prefix /home/<user>/.local/
make
```

I run into issues when I try to install with `make install`. I get the following error:

```
test -z "/home/<user>/.local/lib" || mkdir -p -- "/home/<user>/.local/lib"
 /pkg/fs-foundation-/dynamic/bin/ginstall -c -m 644 'libplibul.a' '/home/<user>/.local/lib/libplibul.a'
tr.dynamic: no tr.dynamic policy could be found for the command 'ginstall'.
```

I've tried Googling this error and I don't get anything. Any idea how to fix it? This is on a RedHat Linux machine.

Comment: No issues here: `./configure --prefix /home/[user]/.local/ && make && make install` (OK with --prefix to any location in /home/[user]/) ... Search 'define tr.dynamic c++', found (first hit) "dynamic memory TR" http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After combing through the `configure` script and the `config.log`, I found that it checked the `INSTALL` environment variable first before choosing `ginstall`. All I had to do was set the install program to `/usr/bin/install` instead like this:

```
./configure INSTALL=/usr/bin/install --prefix /home/<user>/.local
```